# How to use custom template-url as an attribut of HTML element in angular.1x?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, components

Lets say I have such code:

```
<body>
<authentication-form template="./path/to/different/style.HTML" ></authentication>
...
</body>
```

Authentication-form is a component. It has template and simple controller. How to use custom template by adding template-url as an attribut of HTML element in angular.1x? I was trying with binding: {}, but it is probably, not what I'm looking for,

Comment: you cannot define template url at the time whee you declare a component instance in a page. Explain your need, maybe there is something that could help you. A solution based on Angular 1.5 is suitable ?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the component definition?

Your component definition should have a property called templateUrl and you put it there.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

```
angular.module('sample').component('authenticationForm', {
  templateUrl: './path/to/different/style.HTML',
  controller: AuthenticationFormController,
  bindings: {}
});
```

Then your html is much more simple:

```
<authentication-form></authentication-form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My component looks like you wrote, but I'm looking for different way. I even don't know if it is possible to do it different way - this is why I asked.

Comment: Why do you need the template path in the html?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My component looks like that:

```
angular.module("authentication")
       .component("authentication", {
            templateUrl: function($element, $attrs) {
                return $attrs.templateUrl;
            },
            controller: AuthenticationCtrl,
        });
```

in index.html I have:

```
<body>
     <authentication template-url="./path/to/template.html></authentication>
</body>
```

It works without bindings... and I'm not sure if it's ok.